# Bringing two laptops from UK to EU and back, one bought in UK and one in EU Pre-Brexit

Tags: uk, airports, italy

I've read different threads on this topic, but I'm opening a new one because my situation is quite peculiar:

I want to take two personal laptops with me on a flight to Italy and then bring them back to the UK (I'm resident in UK).

I bought one laptop in the UK and one in Italy, both of them before the Brexit, so I didn't need to declare them anywhere.

What are the rules now? Do I need to declare the one I bought in Italy to British Customs before I take any flights? Even if it's for personal use and I intend to bring it back?

Comment: Where do the two laptops presently reside?

Comment: @CMaster From the OP's statement that they're a UK resident, I assume both laptops are with the OP in the UK.

Comment: yes, it is correct. Both laptops in UK

Answer (score 2):

> What are the rules now?

If you would buy a laptop in Italy now, you would need to declare it when entering the UK and pay VAT. Those are the rules now and the main change brought about by Brexit to the scenario you mentioned.

> Do I need to declare the one I bought in Italy to British Customs before I take any flights?

No, that's not how Brexit works, the laptop been grandfathered in if you will. I don't have a clear citation at hand (and there are a few annoying issues for stuff that was, e.g. bought just before the end of the transition period but returned afterwards) but you can easily see that coming back and collecting duty and import tax for everything that was traded since the UK joined the EU is not workable.

Various new rules are being phased in gradually but generally apply only to goods traded after the end of the transition period.

> Even if it's for personal use and I intend to bring it back?

In theory, that doesn't make a difference. Either it was properly imported and taxed in the first place (which is the case here) and you have no problem or it hasn't and it's perfectly possible to get caught on a subsequent trip (we even had a question from someone who experienced this a few years back).

In practice, carrying some personal electronic equipment is so common that customs officers rarely seem to go to the trouble of checking anything (certainly one laptop and a phone, but usually a couple of devices of each category would be fine as well), even if they do challenge you or take a look at your bags (alcohol, on the other hand…).

In any case, the fact it's for personal use is not enough to completely circumvent customs rules and most laptops would need to be declared when you bring them into the country (current threshold for tax-free imports *for personal use* is £390).

The only relevant fact is therefore the date you bought and imported the laptop. If you really want to document something out of an abundance of caution it has to be this (receipt from the laptop and any proof you resided in the UK should be enough).

Answer (score 1):

They are for personal use, and you are starting your round trip with them.  It will be fine.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so, but my concern is that they will ask me to pay custom fees for the one bought in Italy before the Brexit. Would it be the case? There's a case of a person who was charged for a laptop bought in U.S., long time before, while he was in transit in Germany

Comment: I could maybe see them trying to charge you if it was new in the box, but a used laptop in your carry on bag seems like it would be a stretch.  If you happen to still have a copy of the receipt with the date on it you could bring that for some piece of mine as proof that you bought it when the UK was part of the EU.

Comment: @enrico The key difference is that your laptop was properly imported under the rules of the time, which is not the case for the US/German story.